# On Windows 10 (latest updates) I sometimes have background windows displaying blurry text

Tags: windows-10, dpi

This is from the Terminal Window in Visual Studio Code but it also happens in other apps like the Epic Game Launcher.

[image: Text]

And as soon as I click on the app to make it be the foreground app again, the text is sharp again.

What is the cause of this?

Comment: Is this a laptop with Intel graphics? Is the Intel graphics driver up to date?

Comment: No Desktop with Geforce 980

Comment: I haven't seen this on NVIDIA graphics yet. Still, is the NVIDIA driver up to date? Are you using the stable release?

Comment: yes, yes (more chars to make the editor happy)

Answer (score 0):

The solutions seems to be to go into the Nvidia control panel and then reset everything to defaults:

[image]

Found it here: https://www.sevenforums.com/general-discussion/419600-text-images-appears-blurry-clears-up-if-mouseover-fixed.html